# AS3 gotoAndStop(2); causes a 1009 error second time the frame runs

Tags: actionscript-3, button, null

Disclaimer: I'm really new/incredibly bad at AS3 so it's probably something really stupid that should never happen

Okay so, the first time my main menu frame runs, it runs fine and sends me to the gameplay frame when I press the button. After the gameplay is complete, it returns to the menu frame, and runs fine until I press the same button from before, which calls this error: .

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at Main_fla::MainTimeline/frame2()[Main_fla.MainTimeline::frame2:6]
at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndPlay()
at Main_fla::MainTimeline/easyPress()[Main_fla.MainTimeline::frame3:83]
at Main_fla::MainTimeline/mClickE()[Main_fla.MainTimeline::frame3:45]
```

My code for the button is as follows:

```
buttEasy.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mClickE);
buttHard.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mClickH);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mMove);


function mClickE(e:MouseEvent){


easyPress();
trace("easyP");
menuUsed = true;

}


function easyPress(){
trace("Waited for press and release"); 
sTime = 0;

sTempo =  (6) ;

sBall = 0;

ballSpeed = 7;

gameIsOver = false;

menuUsed = true;

lvlArray0= new Array(1,0,0,2,0,0,1,0,0,3,0,0,1,0,0,2,0,0,1,0,0,3,0,01,0,0,2,0,0,1);

init2 = false;

buttEasy.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mClickE);
stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mMove);

gotoAndPlay(2);


}
```

I honestly have no idea why this is happening. I'm using mouse events instead of button press events and whatnot because my movieclips started disappearing and flashing and other unexplainable stuff...

yeah...

Answer (score 0):

I just registered, so I can't post this as a comment.
Anyway the error occurs on frame 2, not in the script you've provided (which is on frame 3).
You can see this in the error message:
"at Main_fla::MainTimeline/frame2()[Main_fla.MainTimeline::frame2:6]"
-> frame 2 line 6.
There you're accessing something that doesn't exist anymore. (-> something that is now null)
Maybe an object on the stage that has been removed. (But there are a lot of other possibilities, so don't stick with that solution)
Post the script you have on frame 3 for further help.

The flashing and other unexplainable stuff happens, because of this error. It aborts the script and runs the flash normally. (this means that for example the stop(); method won't be executed -> the player runs through all your frames -> the objects on the stage appear to be flashing)

Comment: Line 6 on frame 2 is another stop(); for an object's animation. It does exist on frame 2, and it runs a stop(); successfully for two of the same type of object.

    `KMNK1.stop();
    KMNK2.stop();
    KMNK3.stop();`

1 and 2 are fine, but 3 (which is no different) causes an error...

Comment: This means that KMNK3 must be null, after you returned to the menu once. Since I don't know your code I can't help any further.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably just addressing the "stage" before the reference is given. Start your code with:

```
addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
```

and a handler for this listener

```
private function init(e:Event):void
{
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    // write your code after this
}
```

If you're framescripting (writing AS3 code in a frame) It's not really your problem.
But as the problem states - you're calling some objects property or method witch is null. Your debugger will be able to point to the null object that you try to call on frame 2.